# Как найти строку или слова в StringBuilder

Tags: java

Как найти слово или строку для того чтобы занести её в HashMap в ключ например:

```
#s Ищем эту строку в файле и заносим её в ключ HashMap #e
```

и чтобы когда в тексте находило обозначение `#s` и `#e` то это значение между ними брало и заносило в ключ

Comment: Можно воспользоваться `regexp`-ом.

Comment: не смотри ну например boolean `start = str.startsWith("my"); //true
boolean end = str.endsWith("exe"); //true` а значение между этими строками как занести в хешмап в ключ

Comment: Что-то наподобие этого делает XML парсер